# How to display weather icon in xamarin by calling Openweather API?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, openweathermap

I am working on a XAMARIN App. I am calling open weather API and able to get JSON response.

After string format, I am able to show the City Name + Temperature in the Header (Title).

Still i couldnt bind the Image Icon.

Whatever Bind Image works in the Content Page, but not on the Title.

This piece of syntax is from my Tabbed Main Page .. which calls City Tab Page.

```
 <NavigationPage Title="City" Icon="city.png">
    <x:Arguments>
      <local:CityPage />     
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>
```

and in the city.xaml.cs -  I am calling this method.

```
 public async void GetWeather()
        {
            Weather weather = await Core.GetWeather("07004");
            if (weather != null)
            {
                this.BindingContext = weather;

                string sWeather = String.Format("{0}°F", weather.Temperature);

                this.Title = weather.Title + " " + sWeather;             
            }

        }
```

[image]

Image Icon has to come at the end of the Temperature.

Comment: please post the relevant portions of your xaml/code so we can see what you are already doing

Answer (score 2):

use `StringFormat` :

```
<Label Text={Binding Value, StringFormat='{0}° F'} ... />
```

Comment: this helps.. to fix the degree and F. I need to get the Image Icon.. Display Icon variable which i have commented.. i need to displya

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to bind the url to an image

```
<ContentView Style="{StaticResource fieldView}">
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label  x:Name="tempLabel" Text="{Binding Temperature}" Style="{StaticResource fieldStyle}" />
    <Image Source="{Binding DisplayIcon}" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Thank you Jason ... this.Title = txtLoc.Text + " " + tempLabel.Text + imgIcon;     ImgIcon is my name of the ImageSource. I need to concatenate the image with my string .. my syntax is not working..

Comment: You can't add an image to a standard label.  Use a StackLayout to composite a Label and Image next to each other.

Comment: i have mentioned the same in my xaml syntax and in the code behind : this.Title = txtLoc.Text + " " + tempLabel.Text;  - However, i am not able to get the temperature & image

Comment: if you want to show your code, please edit your question.  Editing my response to include your non-working code is just confusing.  The edit you suggested contained a ContentView with multiple children.  A ContentView can only have one child - if you want multiple elements, you need to contain them in a StackLayout or other container.